# Get image height of hidden image

Tags: jquery, image

My page is divided into multiple tabs, corresponding to hidden divs. One of the tabs has images, and I need to get the height of the images as the client sees it. I've been using `image.clientHeight`, `$(image).height()`, etc. but these all return 0 when the image is not visible on the page.

My question is, is there any way to avoid this—i.e. get the height of image before the client sees it?

And to clarify, I'm looking for the height of the image as it appears on the client's page, not the original, full height of the image.

**EDIT:** So this is how my code is essentially laid out:

```
<div id="page1">
    <h1>Some landing page here</h1>
</div>

<div id="page2" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Images</h1>
    <img src="..."></img>
</div>
```

When the page loads, page1 is shown and all the others are hidden. I know all about checking when an image loads, the window loads, etc. but `$(image).height()` or all other variations of that don't work unless the image is visible to the client (i.e. page2 is shown). Is this intentional? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Show some code! We can't say what is wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: @RaajNadar updated!

Answer (score 1):

I think this happened because of image is not load. So, try something like this.

```
$('#myimg').on("load",function(){
    var imgHeight = img.get(0).height;
    var imgWidth = img.get(0).width;
})​
```

Comment: @downvoter what is wrong with this answer? Even this guy has a valid point.

Comment: @DanielBeck nope. HTMLImageElement.height|width will return the height|width properties/attributes. If not set, these props will be the same as clientHeight|clientWidth.

Comment: @DanielBeck in your answer you are using `$(element).height()` which will call `getComputedStyle(element).height` which is completely different than HTMLImageElement.height property.

Comment: Yes.  So is the person who asked the question.

Comment: @DanielBeck nope they clearly stated that they first tried `clientHeight`.

Comment: They said they tried both, but mea culpa. I'll admit I didn't fully understand jquery's internals there; thought `.height()` was the same as `clientHeight` (and am more used to coping with jquery's behavior.)

Comment: Yeah, I already have checks for image and window loading; I know that's not the problem. The problem is when the image is not visible to the client, it has a height of 0. Updated the original post for clarifications.